# Elementary differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to this community so please forgive me for my poor question formation.

I am facing problem to resolving the DE:

> $(x^2+y^2)y' = 2x^2 - y^2 $

I tried to solve this question by separable method and integrating factor method but i could not able to solve (Resolve) this so please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a [first order homogeneous differential equation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/differential-equations-homogeneous.html).

Answer (score 2):

HINT: write your equation in the form
$$\left(1+\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)^2\right)y'(x)=2-\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)^2$$ and set $\frac{y}{x}=u$ and $$x\ne 0$$

Comment: That is the right method of solving this. Because x and y are homogeneous in the equation.

Comment: done that and got up to $$\int \frac{1 + u^2}{2-u^2-u-u^3} \, dv = \int dx/x $$

Comment: can you fix it please?

Comment: i think it must be $du$

Comment: the RHS is: $\ln(x)$ but the left is what i cannot evaluate

Comment: the left integral is difficult

Comment: yes i made a mistake its $du$